# Is the limit of an uniformly convergent sequence of integrable functions (with convergent integrands) integrable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

My question is the following:

Consider a sequence $\{\,f_{n}\}$ of Lebesgue integrable functions  over $\mathbb R$ that converges uniformly. Assume furthermore that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f_{n}\,dx\,\to\,c\in\mathbb R.
$$
It is not necessary that if the limit function $f$ is integrable its integral has the same value, i.e. $\lim \int f_{n} \neq \int \lim f_{n}$, see for example the function $f_{n} = \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[-n,n]}$ with $\int f_{n} = 1$ for all $n \in N$, but $\int \lim f_{n} = 0$. However, the function $f$ is itegrable. Is this true in general, is this function $f$ always integrable?

See remark under: I actually want to assume that all $f_{n}$ are positive (and so $f$ too).

Comment: To give part of the solution myself: assume $x \in [n-1,n)$ and define $g(x) = 1/n$ if $x \in [n-1,n-1/2)$ and $g(x) = -1/n$ if $x \in [n-1/2,n)$. Define furthermore $f_{n}(x) = g(x) \chi_{[0,n)}$. It is seen that $\int f_{n} = 0$ for all $n \in N$ and $f_{n}$ converges to $g$ uniformly. However $g$ itself is not (Lebesgue) integrable. Therefore, we need to add the assumption $\int | f_{n} | \to c$ (or $f_{n}(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in R$).

Comment: When you assume $f_n \geqslant 0$: Fatou's lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\chi_{[k-1,k]}$.

Then $f_n$ converges uniformly, the $f_n$'s are integrable, $\int f_n$ also converges, but the limit does not belong to $L^1$.

If you assume that $f_n\ge 0$, then Fatou's Lemma provides that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}f=\int_{\mathbb R}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\, f_n\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R} f_n,
$$
and hence $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: See remark above, I want to assume that all $f_{n}$ are non-negative and these are I am afraid. Thanks for your help anyway, your counterexample is slightly nicer constructed than mine, ;).